# why redis memory usage is increasing fast, but the keys amount is not changing?

Tags: redis

see the munin graph:

[image]
[image]

redis db keys amount are as usual,
but memory usage is increasing fast.

Why ?

Comment: More data written to the keys? Fragmentation? Please add more information to your question such as what is your Redis doing and the output of `INFO`

Answer (score 0):

Met similar issue.  with Set keys timeout error logs.
" Exception when set *** detail Timeout performing SET (5000ms)"
Keys total count not changed, but memory usage increase every time when setting new values for these keys.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Are you saying that there is a memory leak with the default set keys timeout value? That seems unlikely, but if all other factors are default as well (simple settings). More detail here would make this answer useful.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason. DevOps passed wrong information. Memory lacking caused redis pod restarted several times.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).